# Adding an overlay background in CSS

Tags: css

I have the following png file (see First Image). I need to add a blue overlay to the background so that it looks like the second image. How can I do that using CSS?

[image: First Image]
[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 0):

The best supported cross-browser way to accomplish is to actually make two images, one blurry and the other not blurry, and then cascading them atop one another.

```
body { 
  background: url(images/bg-solid.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#page-wrap { 
  background: url(images/bg-blurry.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  width: 500px; margin: 40px auto;
}
```